# How to get all sheets names and its specific cell value using macro/vba?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I already have a code for getting all sheets names into a cell, but I also want to get the value of specific cell in every sheets.

[image]

Comment: So what have you tried and where did you run into problems? Without that information this question is not complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code assumes you have a sheet called "List" where you want the values for the other sheets to appear.

```
Sub ListSheets()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim x As Integer

x = 1


For Each ws In Worksheets
     If ws.Name <> "List" Then
        Sheets("List").Cells(x - 1, 1) = ws.Name
        Sheets("List").Cells(x - 1, 2) = ws.Range("a1").Value
     End If
     x = x + 1
     
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this now i got an idea on how should i do it.
Here's what i did!

Sub ListAllSheets()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Counter As Integer

Counter = 0

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ActiveCell.Offset(Counter, 0).Value = ws.Name
    ActiveCell.Offset(Counter, 1).Value = ws.Range("a1")

    Counter = Counter + 1
Next ws

End Sub